# IE6 CSS float problems

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with the floating side panel. It looks ok in Firefox but i think its being push by somthing in IE as it appears at the bottom on the page.

The url is: www.sellandrentbackhouse.co.uk

I have tried making the blog look the same as the websites but this appears pushed out even in firefox. I cant find out whats wrong. AHHHH!

Any ideas? www.sellandrentbackhouse.co.uk

Comment: Can you more specifically describe the problem?

Comment: -1 For caring about IE6 users.  Seriously.

Comment: +1 to counter the above.  I don't work with Ian, but at our company, about 60% of our users use IE6.  We would LOVE to change that fact.  But just because it isn't our fault that IE6 sucks, doesn't mean that it isn't our responsibility to make our product work for our paying customers.

Answer (score 1):

IE6 doesn't always float things correctly when the widths of two items are close to 100% of the width of their container.  You can try a couple of things to correct this:

1. Add margin-right:-20px; to your #main div
2. Float the content left and float the sidePanel right